# Library for password protecting PDF from copying, editing and printing (not viewing)

Tags: c++, c, pdf

I'm looking for a good and lightweight library (preferably C or C++) to password protect PDF files from copying, editing and printing. Preferably free or cheap commercial variant, since i want library only to use this functionality.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Haru Free PDF library](http://libharu.sourceforge.net/). The examples suggest [setting permissions](http://libharu.sourceforge.net/demo/permission.c) should be possible.

Comment: Thank you for the effort, but this library doesnt seem to support existing PDFs. I voted you up anyway.